# CSS FireFox image container keeps ascept ratio

Tags: css, firefox

I have a horizontal container for image thumbnails with specified height (80px) and in the container there are several thumbnails like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail-container fullHeight">
   <img class="fullHeight" />
</div>
```

And css:

```
.thumbnail-container {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: top;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.fullHeight {
   height:100%;
}
```

Now the problem is that ONLY in FF, the container keeps the aspect ratio, so that if the image original size is 300x168 px it gets resized to 143x80 px, but the container keeps the width 300px.

Here is the screenshot of how it looks in all other browsers and in FF.

[image]

Note that there is no padding inside.

Comment: instead of giving the container a height of 100%, whhy not just set its height to 80px and width auto if that's the height you want it to be?

Comment: @Pete I didn't think that would solve it, but it did! Thanks! Anyway, I don't get what's the problem with height 100%...

Comment: Not sure either. I tried with your code and it seemed to work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/pdkx6hsu/

Answer (score 0):

One way out is to set a fixed width and height so that image size does not change from one browser to another , for that you will have to add the following:

```
.thumbnail-container {
   display: inline-block;
   MARGIN-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: top;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.fullHeight {
   width:300px;//added
   height:168px;//added
}
```